# Многие к многим, EF Core, Создать или изменить запись

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Не получается сделать запись в БД, когда связь многие к многим(many to many) Умоляю спасти мою нервную систему.
Модели:

```
public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PermissionRole> PermissionRoles { get; set; }

    public Permission()
    {
        PermissionRoles = new List<PermissionRole>();
    }
}  
[Table("AspNetRoles")]
public class MyIdentityRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string AltName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PermissionRole> PermissionRoles { get; set; } 


    public MyIdentityRole() : base()
    {
        PermissionRoles = new List<PermissionRole>();
    }
    public MyIdentityRole(string name, string altName)
   : base(name)
    {
        AltName = altName;
    }
} 

   public class PermissionRole
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PermissionId { get; set; }
        public string RoleId { get; set; }

        public MyIdentityRole Role { get; set; }

        public Permission Permission { get; set; }
    }
```

Попытка сделать запись:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<String> EditRole(string roleId, List<string> permissions)
{
    MyIdentityRole role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);
    Permission perm = _permissionContext.Permission.Where(p => permissions.Contains(p.Id.ToString())).FirstOrDefault();

    PermissionRole permissionRole = new PermissionRole()
    {
        Role = role,
        Permission = perm
    };


    _permissionRoleContext.Add(permissionRole);

    _permissionRoleContext.SaveChanges();


    return "" + perm.Name;
}
```

Что здесь не правильно?

Comment: `PermissionRole permissionRole = new PermissionRole(){PermissionId = perm.id,RoleId = role.Id }` ?

Comment: @tym32167 уже как только не извращался... Так тоже не пашет пишет SQL ошибку “Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF” with composite key

Comment: тогда может `MyIdentityRole role = await _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);` ==> ` _permissionContext.Roles.Where(...).Single()`? Типа роль из того же контекста получить?

Comment: ну, или там есть что то типа `context.Roles.Attach(Role)` - это тоже можно попробовать, но я дословно не помню, как оно делается )

Comment: Помнится на ru so у Павла Майорова был где-то ответ, в котором это подробно расписывалось. Попробуйте поискать, я сам к сожалению сегодня почти весь день в оффлайне.

Comment: “Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF” - на какой таблице появляется?

Comment: @n.piskunov почему то на таблице юзеров хотя вставка должна происходить в таблице где сопоставление идет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF” with composite key –

Нужно больше подробностей при вставке в какую таблицу наблюдаете эту ошибку. Похоже что в EF-model не хватает DbGenerated для Id. Судя по composite key, вы видимо пытаетесь вставить сгенерированный на стороне приложения Id для сущности PermissionRole (видимо это ваша m2m таблица связки в БД);

Попробуйте так:

```
   public class PermissionRole
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    public MyIdentityRole Role { get; set; }

    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Сработало. Боже мой, из за одной аннотации, столько времени потерял, спасибо!